# How to set which field is mandatory based on condition when passing in API in Java using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Say I have two different APIs: A and B, that get the same POJO  C.
POJO C has 2 different fields x and y.

```
public class C
{
String x;
String y;
}
```

Is it possible to set some conditional validation annotation,
so when passing POJO c to API A, only field x is mandatory,
and while for API B, both fields x and y are mandatory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validations for this kind of scenario

For example :-

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class C {
    
    @NotEmpty
    String X;

    String Y;
    
}
```

And you may also decide for the use of @NotEmpty over @NotNull for checking if it is not empty.

And on controller level you can make use of something like below:-

```
methodGet(@Valid @RequestBody final C c)
```

this methodGet = controller level method

Answer (score 0):

Since you want different validations for the same POJO. You will have to use custom validation.

Basically you will have to create 2 custom annotaions. And then apply those annotaions on your respective Apis.

You can follow this tutorial.

[Custom Validator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do it, would be using validation groups. Please try :

Controller :

```
@RestController
public class FooController {
    @PostMapping("/api1")
    public Foo foo(@Validated(Api1Validated.class) Foo foo) {
        return foo;
    }
    @PostMapping("/api2")
    public Foo foo2(@Validated(Api2Validated.class) Foo foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Domain class :

```
@Data
public class Foo {
    @NotEmpty(groups = {Api1Validated.class, Api2Validated.class})
    private String name;
    @NotNull(groups = {Api2Validated.class})
    private Integer age;
}
```

Validation interfaces :

```
public interface Api1Validated {
}

public interface Api2Validated {
}
```

Unit test :

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class FooControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("foo");
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api1")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api2")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

Versions : spring boot 2.3.4, junit 5.7.0